# LuisRecognizer result doesn't show " Value " field in DateTimeV2 resolution Json

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to extract dateTime using LUIS.

Environment: BotFramework V4
Lang: c#/ .NET

I am using the built in recognizer to extract Date / Time provided by the user.

```
var recognizerResult = await_services.LuisServices[LuisKey].RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject Entities1 = recognizerResult?.Entities;
```

Now when I am printing this JSON file I am not getting the " Value " field in the Resolution portion.This is the JSON response I am getting when i extract the entities.

```
Query String : fly on 20 mar return on 24 mar Entities Returned { "$instance": { “datetime”: [ { “startIndex”: 7, “endIndex”: 13, “text”: “20 mar”, “type”: “builtin.datetimeV2.date” }, { “startIndex”: 24, “endIndex”: 30, “text”: “24 mar”, “type”: “builtin.datetimeV2.date” } ] }, “datetime”: [ { “type”: “date”, “timex”: [ “XXXX-03-20” ] }, { “type”: “date”, “timex”: [ “XXXX-03-24” ] } ] }
```

I have tried using the `includeAPIResult : true` parameter when creating the recognizer. Still the same results. Kindly suggest what am I doing wrong.
And how can I extract proper Date time from the json response.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so [this is an known issue right now](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1348) if you choose to use the `LuisRecognizer` package. Essentially it "eats" important details of the raw LUIS response.

My professional recommendation would be to eschew `LuisRecognizer` and just use the full on `LuisClient` directly. The only real reason to use `LuisRecognizer` is if you want that extra level of abstraction that allows you to work with other recognizer implementations. If you're "all in" on LUIS, then you probably want access to the full fidelity of LUIS anyway.

Comment: ANy working example of LuisClient ? And resolution of pre-built date-time entity.

Answer (score -1):

I do something like this:

```
luisResults.Entities.MyDateEntity?[0].Expressions?[0]
```

It will then result to a string that I parse to dateTime. Given that luis successfully sets MyDateEntity value.

Comment: I think this is not related to the question as having the raw luis result not parsed as an entity when using LuisRecognizer, is the root problem of the question.